# Excel fragmentary unicode support - can it change?

Tags: vba, excel, unicode, locale

If I use unicode symbol in Excel files, its some part looks correct, some times - no.

As example I use Russian, and macro assign label for UserForm window, key, form element, and for MsgBox calling button.
But in form element it looks correct, in UserForm head - i see ???, and in MsgBox too.

You can see into this screenshot:
[image: problem]

Or use this file for test this:
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AgThWBJfRj69vBbRCIWgvMjHq-nm

So, if you know way to slowe this problem (I need show all symbol) - write me

This problem have solution - change locale for non-unicode symbol. But I can't do this into all my client computer, as example.

Comment: I wonder what happens if you hard-code the symbols using `.Frame1.Caption = Chr(123)&Chr(456) etc.` Then ofcourse you need to fill in the right ascii numbers for the symbols

Comment: This is due to lacking unicode support. There are workarounds like [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.office.developer.vba/O0_MG0n9tOU) but they're really cumbersome.

Comment: @Luuklag ASCII != Unicode. You will at least need `ChrW()` to get a unicode character (see [Chr, ChrW Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/613dxh46(v=vs.90).aspx)).

Comment: thanks,its some part help me:

Comment: https://pastebin.com/tWEVGAFm
its help for MsgBox, but how can apply for UserForm head and for Inputbox?

Comment: For a UserForm the approach you posted doesn't work. Therefore you need a completely different approach. Have a look [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/microsoft.public.office.developer.vba/O0_MG0n9tOU/kmGVLwKBcK0J) to get an idea. Doing this is fiddling around a lot there is no neat solution.